Is a high-amp car alternator three phase or single phase power? (12 V, 150 A machine)
I am in mechanical engineering, and have only worked with three-phase power. I modeled a 12V, 150A car alternator as a three-phase electrical machine simply based on when I look up what most alternators are, google says 3-phase. My professor corrected me and said it's probably single-phase. How can I know this without taking the alternator apart? I'm pretty sure it can be installed as a three-wire or single-wire configuration if that helps anything.

Count the number of conductors coming out of the alternator. If there are two it must be single phase. If there's three or four it could be three phase.

@LordTeddy Do you mean two conductors out of the alternator, or the stator? Generally, a 3-phase alternator includes the diode rectifier bridges and maybe even the regulator so you do get two wires out - but rectified three-phase.

DC generators still exist but 99.99% of all car generators are nowadays 3-phase AC with a diode bridge rectifier built-in.

Car alternators are very much multi-phase and generally 3-phase: -

Image from AC Lab - Automotive Alternator as AC Generator. Here's a 3-phase delta wound one from this video: -

If you google car alternator schematic you'll get tons of hits showing three-phase alternators.

My professor corrected me and said it's probably single-phase.

Obviously not a professor with the right qualifications or maybe he was having a bad day or, maybe you misheard him?

How can I know this without taking the alternator apart?

Well, I'm not ruling out there might be more than 3 phases of course but, it's highly unlikely that it will be single phase. If you have an oscilloscope you can look at the unconnected output waveform and, if it looks like a bridge rectified output (without smoothing) then it can only be a single phase device (however unlikely). If it looks like this: -

Then it's a multi-phase winding with a multi-phase bridge-rectifier. Last image from Uncontrolled Rectifiers.
